# How can I parse the second XML tag?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file online resembling this:

```
<example>
    <date>2012-10-13</date>
    <bob>What I already know how to get</bob>
</example>
<example>
    <date>2012-10-14</date>
    <bob>What I want as well as the above</bob>
</example>
```

Here's what I'm using to get the data in the "What I already know how to get" tag:

```
/**
 * Gets be called on opening tags like: <tag> Can provide attribute(s), when
 * xml was like: <tag attribute="attributeValue">
 */
@Override
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
        String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("example")) {
        this.in_example = true;
    } else if (localName.equals("bob")) {
        this.in_bob = true;
    }
}

/**
 * Gets be called on closing tags like: </tag>
 */
@Override
public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("example")) {
        this.in_example = false;
    } else if (localName.equals("bob")) {
        this.in_bob = false;
    }
}

/**
 * Gets be called on the following structure: <tag>characters</tag>
 */
@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    if (this.in_bob) {
                    // A custom DataParser
        myDataParser.setExtractedString(new String(ch, start, length));
    }
}
```

Ok, so here's the question... how can I get "What I want as well as the above", even though it's enclosed in similar tags to "What I already know how to get"?

Thanks in advance :)

N.B. The XML document like a forecast, so the date and the content of the other tags will always be changing.

Comment: have you tried using dom parser??

Answer (score 1):

If your file contains two `<example>` elements at the top level then it is not a well-formed XML document, so an XML parser will always give you a failure when you try to parse it.

It is however a well-formed XML external entity, so you can parse it by including it into a well-formed XML document using an entity reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the answers to a `List` of `Strings`.

Modify the last function as such:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

/**
 * Gets be called on the following structure: <tag>characters</tag>
 */
@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    if (this.in_bob) {
                    // A custom DataParser
        results.add(new String(ch, start, length));
    }
}
```

After you finished walking through the xml, just parse the collected `Strings`.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Kay noted, the document as shown is not valid XML.

Since you seem to have been able to parse and get the first value, I assume it's actually just part of a larger document.

If you want to collect data from more elements, you'll need to collect into a structure like a list rather than just a string, and properly control when you create a new entry in that list.

But the `characters` method doesn't work with the parser in quite the way you seem to think.  It can be called multiple times by the parser for the content within a single tag.  Instead of expecting to get it all at once, you need to collect data into a buffer and only expect it to be complete when `endElement` is called.

For collecting only the "bob" data into a list of strings, the following will do:

```
public class ExampleHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                             String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equals("bob")) {
            builder.setLength(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equals("bob")) {
            results.add(builder.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
        builder.append(ch, start, length);
    }

    public List<String> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
}
```

If you want to collect the other data as well, it will of course be more complex, and you'll collect into something other than a list of strings, but this should give the basic idea.